# Stop Erlang Daemon

Tags: erlang, daemon

Besides running `$ killall -9 beam.smp`, how can I kill an Erlang node programmatically when I know its `-sname`?

If I don't want the heartbeat monitor to restart the process, how can I ensure that whatever answer is given for the above question will also kill the heartbeat?

Is there a decent guide to deploying Erlang as a daemon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`kill` and `killall` with `-9` is *almost always wrong*.

You can quite easily ask the remote node to exit using:

```
rpc:call(RemoteNode, init, stop, []).
```

I don't know whether that'd prevent `heart` from restarting it, but I'd suggest that if you expect to stop it, you shouldn't run it in a don't-ever-stop mode.

**Update** - Zed points out that `init:stop` does the right thing with `heart`, so the above `rpc:call` is the best and only way to do it.

Comment: "init:stop(): ... If the -heart command line flag was given, the heart program is terminated before the Erlang node terminates. ..."

Comment: I think my nodes aren't quite connecting. I'm sure I'm overlooking something. To test, I opened two Terminal windows and ran `erl -sname foo` in one, then got the cookie from it and ran `erl -sname bar -setcookie '...'`. In this window, I ran `net_adm:ping('foo@elife')` but it gave me a 'pang'. I've tried some variants on this, all without luck. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing `-setcookie` on one and not the other?  If they don't match, you can't talk.  In generally, I just use `~/.erlang.cookie` on my local node.

Comment: I set them both to use the same cookie, but still, no communication. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a number of things.  You should definitely have that working, though.  That's another question or more documentation, though.  You could try `-name something@127.0.0.1` which should probably work.

Comment: Are you running OS X? If so, this might be your problem as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136918/getting-two-erl-shells-to-talk