# Erlang nodes can't see each other

Tags: erlang

I am new to Erlang and trying to set two nodes on my laptop.

In one terminal I type:

```
eli@elimayost: ~/erlang_apps> erl -sname foo -setcookie secret
```

And in the second terminal:

```
eli@elimayost: ~/erlang_apps> erl -sname bar -setcookie secret
```

If I use the first terminal to ping the second:

```
(foo@elimayost)1> net_adm:ping(bar@elimayost).
```

I get a pang response (same response if I use the second term to ping the first term).

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you execute `erl_epmd:names()` and post the output?

Comment: I merged your unregistered account into your registered one. You can now leave comments under answers, edit your question, etc. I converted your previous answer to a comment under @mjcopple's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try starting the nodes like this:

```
eli@elimayost: ~/erlang_apps> erl -sname foo@elimayost -setcookie secret
eli@elimayost: ~/erlang_apps> erl -sname bar@elimayost -setcookie secret
```

Then ping them like you did before.

```
(foo@elimayost)1> net_adm:ping(bar@elimayost).
```

If that doesn't work for you, try pinging the node from itself.

Comment: Also look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136918/getting-two-erl-shells-to-talk

Comment: mjcopple: Thanks for your answer. I started the nodes as you suggested.
Still they can not see each other. I can ping both nodes from within the node but not from the other node. I am trying it on OpenSUSE 11.3.
When trying on Ubuntu 10.04 it works fine. Both machines are virtual machines running under Virtual Box.

Answer (score 1):

Did You check the syslog for errors?

Is apparmor active? Maybe turn it off and try again. One day I had very strange effects with apparmor running... but it is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

it's a DNS problem, your host name 'elimayost' can't be found on the DNS. You can use 'localhost' as the host part, which like 'foo@localhost' and 'bar@localhost', it will always work.