# Can't get two Erlang nodes to communicate

Tags: erlang, distributed, distributed-computing

No matter what I try, I can't get two different nodes to communicate. This is probably a very simple problem to solve.

I have created the file .cookie.erlang and I've placed it into my home directory. Then I open a terminal window and type the following commands:

```
erl -sname user1@pc
erlang:set_cookie(node(),cookie).
```

In another terminal window I type:

```
erl -sname user2@pc
erlang:set_cookie(node(),cookie).
```

Now if I type the following command in the first terminal window:

```
net_adm:ping(user2@pc).
```

I always get "false" as result, meaning that the two nodes were not able to connect to each other. I don't understand what I am missing here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erlang nodes can't see each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483471/erlang-nodes-cant-see-each-other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely make sure that 'pc' is the *actual* hostname of your machine.  If it's not, make sure you're using that.

Alternatively, since you're using sname and both hosts are on the same machine, you could get away with doing `erl -sname user1` and `erl -sname user2`.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, thanks :) However, isn't it possible to use a hostname that is different from the one of my machine?

Comment: You can indeed, however you need to make sure that whatever you put after the @ resolves to the proper machine. For example, you can do an IP address (user1@127.0.0.1) or a hostname you put into the hosts file (user1@whatever_host_from_hosts_file_that_resolves_to_me). Erlang just needs to be able to find the target host.

Answer (score 0):

This is a DNS problem, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469730/1526656), which the answer of a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks mostly a DNS issue. You should update it in */etc/hosts* if you are on a Unix based OS, if it is on the same machine you can always use **localhost** that will be reachable:

```
erl -sname a@localhost -cookie aloha
```

Then in a separate terminal:

```
erl -sname b@localhost -cookie aloha
```

With that you should be able to communicate nodes just fine.