# How do I use an OTP application that's already running from a module?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251608/can-i-use-an-existing-otp-application-inside-another-application-or-module) yesterday about using one application inside another.
Let's say I want to use an application called `x` inside a new module `y`.
`x` is already compiled and for the sake of simplicity, lets assume it is already running on localhost, and that the objective is to run both components in different nodes.

How can I call functions of `x` from within `y`?
Would something like `rpc:call(Node, x, Fun, Param)` work?

Furthermore, is any (network) setup necessary in order to use the `rpc` module?

**Important**

If you are not able to test connections between two nodes, make sure that you use the command line flag `-name` and that you include the whole name in your `net_adm:ping/1` call. e.g. if you named your node `x@localhost`, you must ping `x` from another module by executing `net_adm('x@localhost').`. Notice the single-quotes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136918/getting-two-erl-shells-to-talk-on-os-x) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you call `x` depends both on its APIs and on whether or not `x` is running in the same node as `y`.

- If `x` is running in the same node as `y` and your application dependencies are declared such that `x` starts before `y` starts, you can simply call into a module of `x` the same as calling any other local module.
- If `x` is in a different node, then yes, using [the `rpc` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html) to call into it is one viable option. As long as the `y` node can connect to the `x` node via [Distributed Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html), `rpc` will work without any extra setup.

I mention the API because it's frequently the case that modules do their work by registering their process ids into some sort of name registry, such as the local registry via [`erlang:register/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#register-2), [the global registry](http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html), or alternative registries such as [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc), and callers may need to first access the registry directly or indirectly to find the target they're trying to call. For example, when calling a [`gen_server` instance](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) you typically need to pass as an argument the name or pid of the instance you're trying to call, and for remote calls, the target node name is needed as well.

Comment: Thank you!! The nodes are supposed to be different, I forgot to mention that. However useful your answer is, I'm trying to connect to the `x` node by initiating a new shell with `erl -name y@127.0.0.1 -setcookie y`. I try to ping `x` using `net_adm:ping(x).` but it responds with `pang`. Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the name of the `x` node? If you have an Erlang shell open on the `x` node its name should be in the shell prompt. Was `x` started with short names (using `-sname`) or long names (using `-name`)? Are you sure it's using the same cookie? If you run `epmd -names` does it list the `x` node? Just a guess but I suspect the `127.0.0.1` part should be the hostname instead.

Comment: Running `node().` on `x` outputs `x@127.0.0.1`. That's why I named `y` `y@127.0.0.1`. I believe both are using long names (`-name`), not short ones. I fetch the cookie from `x` by running `erlang:get_cookie().` on its console, which outputs `x`. So I start `y` with `erl -name y@127.0.0.1 -setcookie x`, but results remain the same.  
What also intrigues me is that running `net_adm:names()` outputs `{ok,[{"x",58521},{"y",58920}]}` and `epmd -names` outputs `name y at port 58920`, `name x at port 58521`.

Comment: I figured it out. I have to use `net_adm:ping('x@127.0.0.1').`. I thought that `net_adm:ping(x).` would be enough, but apparently not! I got the idea from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136918/getting-two-erl-shells-to-talk-on-os-x).

Comment: I'll buy you a round of beers if you come to Lisbon anytime soon. Thank you again for all your help. You are awesome.

Comment: Glad you figured out the ping problem, and you're welcome for the help.