# Is there a way to kill the erlang vm when it is running with -heart?

Tags: erlang, heartbeat, zotonic

The title pretty much sums it up. I have a zotonic site running with -heart, it uses lots of cpu time and I can't get an erlang shell. So, is there a way to kill the vm? `killall heart` and `killall beam.smp` are not working.

I found this question:
[Stop Erlang Daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130644/stop-erlang-daemon)
, but it does not really answer my question.

Comment: In my experience first killing heart followed by killing beam or beam.smp does the trick.

Comment: @Steve I did try that without success. I have since found the problem of not being able to get a shell, namely this: http://groups.google.com/group/zotonic-users/browse_thread/thread/b3971b574e405bcc?pli=1. So I solved this by solving the underlying issue it seems :). Still, I think how to do this should be better documented (somewhere).

Comment: Kill heart and then beam, in one command line. Always works for me. We (the Zotonic team) are looking at non-heart solutions.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this: I much prefer supervisord to heart - it's behavior is more easily customizable and it works for non-erlang things, meaning as you learn its nuances those learnings are more applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
init:stop().
```

It will kill the heart process and all applications.

Comment: But he said he can't get an Erlang shell, because the process is using too much CPU, so I don't think this helps in this particular case.

Comment: When I tried this from `remsh`, `heart` didn't die and it restarted the `remsh` node and the original node.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.... 
And it was really hard to kill it.
I tried the normal paths and couldn't do it.
So I did this hack:

First let's get the PID

```
sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      931/beam.smp
```

So the PID is 931.

Next which program created that process?

```
lsof -p 931 | grep txt
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/agarcia/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
beam.smp 931 yaws  txt    REG     8,1  2053256 22793377 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.8.5/bin/beam.smp
```

So the program is .../bin/beam.smp
so just move it

```
mv beam.smp old_beam.smp
```

And now you kill it

```
kill -9 931
```

And I finally was able to kill it :-)

It's  a testament to erlangs reliability that one actually needs to hack-it in order to be able to take down the service.

ps: I originally tried yaws -I [pid] --stop but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind killing every VM on your machine:

```
ps aux | grep -e heart -e epmd | grep -v grep | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | xargs kill -9
```

The VM and `heart` seem to monitor each other mutually. In case the VM is in a crash/revive loop, you may need to run this command several times quickly to kill everything dead.